# how to change app for mirror comment facebook page and web

Tags: facebook

I have lost admin right to the facebook app which are using for manage fb comments plugin on my website. Which are mirror to the facebook page.

All the comments on website and facebook page for the same url still sync and mirror. but I have no right to control the app.

So, I have created a new app and tried to re-mirror the website with same page as before but under new app.. I accept that may be all the old comment will be not control or update on new app.. but I'm the admin of page and new app but I can not work out this situation.

The list which are show the page for mirror is not show that page, only other page i'm admin on..

I have included the picture below: showing that I'm the admin of page, but no page listed on mirror.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97vxd.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3WyL.jpg]

kind regrds

Comment: Did you use Facebook’s debug tool to refresh their cache of your URL’s meta data, after you changed the ones relevant for moderation?

Comment: yes it is, in debug tool, for the old url which are sync between page and web, I can see that url in comment manager , ( love this ) .. but for the new url with new comment.. it not sync anyway.. .. , under the comment box in website it not show the notice " this comment will show on page ... "    . I think that why we need to chose the page from list on setting for comment of app which because I dont see that page on my app :(

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to activate comment mirroring for the same FB page from two different apps. Might be that the page would need to be removed from the previous app first.

Comment: yep.. but i lose admin right from old app. dont understand why i have full control on my website and my page.. but they not allow to use other app.. :) looking for answer now..